# how to show keyboard on a editText inside a floating view added by an android service

Tags: android, service, view, android-softkeyboard, floating

I have a service that add and display a view in frontground of other apps. There is an editText in the view. I want to be able to type in the `editText` when it is in focus and when it losts focus, anything typed to be on the background app. I have the codes here but I cannot set the soft keyboard visible. I can type using a hardware keybaord, however. What is wrong?

```
edtTextInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    Log.d("", "Has focus");

                    mParams1.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(
                            mAssistiveView1, mParams1);

                     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                     imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
                } else {
                    Log.d("", "Lost focus");

                    mParams1.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(
                            mAssistiveView1, mParams1);

                     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                     imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

part2 codes added afterwards to show how the view is added:

```
    mParams1.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE  ;

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(ParentView, mParams1);
```

Comment: The first step is to get the keyboard displayed first. Then we can work out to hide it later.

Comment: remember this is a service class so that may be a bit different from an activity

Comment: I tested the code on a tablet, a real device.

Comment: I add some more codes in part2 about how the view is added, may be helpful to you.

Comment: do you have seen output log in OnFocusChange()?

Comment: Yes. I have two editTexts. So when I move to another one in steps, this trigger has focus and lost focus. // 03-03 13:53:19.746: D/(17589): Has focus
03-03 13:53:40.976: D/(17589): Lost focus

Comment: Would it be possible this line needed some changes? mParams1.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE  ;

Answer (score 0):

Try `InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(View, int)` and `InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(IBinder, int)`

Comment: I try: imm.showSoftInput(edtTextInput, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED) inside if (hasFocus) {}; but the keyboard does not show

Answer (score 0):

May be I'am very late but there is the workaround for the same. You can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226445/4024250)

It was asked and answered by myself.

Answer (score -1):

hi you can try my code bellow to hide or show softkeyboard when you want.

```
//hide keyboard
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  //ref to your EditText
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0); //hide keyboard
```

//show keyboard

```
myEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0);
  }
},50);
```

Comment: no soft keyboard shown ; that is put in the body of the class