# Chat head kind of pop up with edit text. But key pad not coming up when clicked inside

Tags: android, popup, chat, android-softkeyboard, head

I have implemented chat head kind of pop up for my application using service. And I have used edit text inside that.

But problem is that when I click on edit text only cursor is visible and keyboard is not coming up. And not even able to select or copy paste the text inside that edit text. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my problem.

I was using the following code earlier:-

Global variables:-

```
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
```

Then in onCreate of Service

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    //Add the view to the window.
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Problem was with **FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE**, use **FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL** instead.

But now again problem was that though I was able to get the keyboard with my floatingView but keypad was not coming for other apps, even back button stopped working.

So to fix this I used button on Floating UI which toggles between enabling keypad on floating UI and disabling that so that back button and keypad works for other apps.

I used the following code for the same:-

```
private void enableKeyPadInput(Boolean enable) {
    mWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(mFloatingView);

    if (enable) {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    } else {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
}
```

If true is passed to this method then keypad starts working. If false is passed then other apps starts working.

This is my workaround for the problem. Is there any other way to achieve the same which is better than this?

Comment: with FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL , other app are not able to open keyboard. How to fix that or am i the only one having the issue ?

Comment: i am also facing the same issue @SimpleCoder. Found any solution to this

Comment: Hi andinrajesh, If you'll pass true to the above function it will start working. You just have to trigger it with true or false, depending of the usage. Read again the solution carefully. May be that will help.

Answer (score -1):

thank @Narendra Jadon

this maybe better

```
private void enableKeyPadInput(Boolean enable) {
        //mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView);


        if (enable) {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        } else {
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }

        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView,params);

        //mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
    }
```